# How to fill a single value in the 'Donut Chart'

Tags: d3.js

I am getting current status from the server. from the server information i need to show the current status of the finished works.

like this :

[image]

I am trying here, but i am not getting result.
here is my code :

```
var data = [45] //say value i get.

var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#ffff00", "#1ebfc5"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 90)
    .innerRadius(radius - 80);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


 var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(color[0]); });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/1427/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just get a full circle, right?

Well, d3 stands for data driven documents, which means that it cannot show data that isn't there.

So basically, to fix it, you just need the counter value in your dataset: I have fixed your code below:

```
var data = [45, 55] //as you see, i have added 55 (100-45).

var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data)
    .range(["#ffff00", "#1ebfc5"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 90)
    .innerRadius(radius - 80);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


 var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(d.data); });
```

**EDIT** 
I also changed your coloring. in the end of your code you do "return color(color[0])" which always returns the same color. So even if you would have 2 different parts in  your donut chart, they whould have been colored the same and you wouldn't have noticed the difference :-). Use the d3 built in data variable. For arcs/pies, the variable d also returns more then just the original data, it returns a custom object. Your data is stored in d.data, which you can see in the code I included.

Comment: Yes, i agree. I am trying to add a html text in to the diagram, but not working as like expected. i am trying to break the text. (not working) here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/1430/ can you help me?

Comment: You cannot add html tags inside svg tags :-). And unfortunately, it also seems so that you can't break svg - text. So I suggest you do an .append("text") twice. If somebody has a better idea or actually does know how to break svg text, i would be very interested to know as well :-)